# Magento getting order grand total in onepage.php

Tags: magento

I'm struggling with a very stupid problem.
I've edited the saveOrder() method in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Type/Onepage.php.
This because I wanted to prevent Magento from sending order confirmation email for some payment methods.
Instead of standard emails I'm sending a new one (coded in transactional emails in backend) with different information.
All it's ok, I've done something like:

```
if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()!='X') {
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
} else {
    $name = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
$mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
    $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
    $emailInfo->addTo($order->getCustomerEmail(), $name);
    $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
$templateId = 3;
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$sender = Array('name'  => 'XXX', 'email' => 'xxx@xxx.xxx');
    $mailer->setSender($sender);
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order' => $order
        )
    );
    $mailer->send();
}
```

All works fine except for the total of the order. In the transactional email I'm printing

```
{{var order.getGrandTotal()}}
```

but I'm getting the value "0.999953719008" for a 1 euro price product and I don't know how to solve this. (The test product has got a discount)
I've tried creating a script which loads a previously registered order and sends the email using the same email template. In this case all works like a charm!
So I suppose that the problem is  because the order isn't saved yet.
I've just tried passing the grand total as another variable using

```
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order' => $order,
            'total' => $order->getGrandTotal()
        )
    );
```

and printing

```
{{var total}}
```

in the template and in this case there isn't any value for the variable.
How can I manage to solve this?

Thank in advance!

p.s.: I'm using an installation of 1.6 version of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before as well. It's due to php float rounding issues:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Use `round()` to display your results correctly to the user. With `bcadd()` you can avoid the rounding issues if you change the price somewhere with custom code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I've already tried this way.
The problem is that if I try to pass $order->getGrandTotal() as additional variable to the mail template and print it out, it gives to me an empty value. Where am I wrong?